# Memory management of a view controller in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following code in the initialiser of a class:

```
UIViewController* blankViewController=[[DisplayViewController alloc] 
                   initWithNibName:@"Blank" bundle:nil];
self.nextView=blankViewController.view;
```

`nextView` is a property that uses retain. Notice that `blankViewController` was not released. If it were released, this would cause a crash as the view doesn't seem to keep a reference to the `viewController`. I want the view controller to stick around as long as a reference to the view is kept. What is the nicest way to fix this memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `blankViewController` as an ivar of `self`, or make it a (static) global variable.

Then, when `self` is deallocated, you call `[blankViewController release]`.

You need to do this because there's no other (documented) way to get the view controller from a view.