# Tricky memory management in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

After reading:
[Memory management of a view controller in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242351/memory-management-of-a-view-controller-in-objective-c)

and

[Does UIView's addSubview really retain the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937767/does-uiviews-addsubview-really-retain-the-view)

I wrote the following code to toggle a subview:

```
@synthesize switchableView, viewSelector, currentSubview;

//...

if(switchableView.subviews.count != 0)
 [[switchableView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]]
self.currentSubview = (veiwSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ?
 [ViewA new] : [ViewB new];
[switchableView addSubview:currentSubview.view];

//[currentSubview release]; //<---crashes if I uncomment this line
```

It seems to run fine if I comment out that release line, but I can't wrap my head around why. Here's the way I understand what happens and maybe someone can tell me where I go wrong:

So lets consider currentView:

- A gets alloc-ed by the 'new'    message--retain count=A:1
- A gets retained by the setter--retain    count=A:2
- A's view gets (supposedly)    retained--retain count=A:2.1

next time through...

- A's subview gets released count=A:2
- B gets alloc-ed by the 'new' message--retain count=B:1, A:2
- A gets autoreleased by the setter-- B:1, A:1
- B gets retained by the setter--B:1, A:1
- nothing ever gets rid of A?

So should I change my code, or am I wrong about the way memory management works in this language...or both?-

Comment: You have an extra ] after removeFromSuperview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of retain and release is correct, as is your code.  That suggests that the problem lies outside of the code you've posted.   For example, you would have this problem if your currentSubView property was defined as `assign` instead of `retain`.

You code is not structured well, however.  This would be much clearer:

```
self.currentSubView = [[ViewA new] autorelease];
```

Furthermore, view *controllers* are meant to be cached, not created and released each time the user toggles a display.  Typically, you create your view controllers beforehand, and access their `.view` property when necessary to display the view. `UIViewController` will automatically deallocate non-visible views in low memory conditions, and re-allocate their view when the `.view` property is accessed.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, step one, ignore the `retainCount`. It's one of those things Apple should rename to something like `lsdjiofsudfoiwjeriowhfiuwhrteiuhweifhsdjkfhsiurwoieuriosfho` so people won't guess it's name, and not list it in the documentation. For your purposes, it's entirely useless, so ignore it.

Now that I've said that, let's consider something: `addSubview:` DOES retain its argument, and `removeFromSuperview` releases the receiver.

Finally, it's hard to tell what `currentSubview` is. It has a `view` property which would lean towards a VC, however, the way you're using it by itself, would indicate its a normal view. Perhaps you can clarify so I can continue my answer.

Comment: lsdjiofsudfoiwjeriowhfiuwhrteiuhweifhsdjkfhsiurwoieuriosfho ... check! So what rules do you go by in O-C? because evidently, that whole releasing or autoreleasing everything you alloc is a bunch of crap.

Comment: These are what I recommend you follow: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html ... Once you learn those few simple rules, you'll be well on your way to understanding a large chunk of what you need to know about memory management here.

Comment: He's not using the retainCount method, he's simply counting his own retain and release using, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the release line to

```
self.currentSubview = nil;
```

and I think you'll be fine. You're releasing, but not setting the property to nil. So, when it gets re-assigned next time through, release will be called again on it. But you already released it so... boom.